# Serialize string to UTF w/o BOM

Tags: c++, c, encoding, utf-8

I'm trying to code unicode string serialization to UTF-8 w/o BOM file. For some reason the code below gives wrong output.

```
static void MyWriteFile(HANDLE hFile, PTCHAR pszText, int cchLen, BOOL bAsUnicode)
{
  DWORD dwBytes;
  size_t utf8len = WideCharToMultiByte(CP_UTF8, 0, pszText, -1, NULL, 0, NULL, NULL);
  PCHAR pszConverted = (PCHAR)LocalAlloc(LPTR, utf8len);

  WideCharToMultiByte(CP_UTF8, 0, pszText, utf8len, pszConverted, utf8len, 0, 0);
  WriteFile(hFile, pszConverted, utf8len, &dwBytes, NULL);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
WideCharToMultiByte(CP_UTF8, 0, pszText, utf8len, pszConverted, utf8len, 0, 0);
```

The fourth parameter of [WideCharToMultiByte](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd374130%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) (cchWideChar) is the size of the input string. You should leave that to -1 as it is null terminated. Otherwise your output buffer is probably not large enough, and it will contain too much data.